# VBA create and write to file with invalid characters

Tags: vba, ms-word

**My VBA Code**

`Dim fso As Object
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Dim Fileout As Object
    Set Fileout = fso.CreateTextFile("C:\users\Home\Desktop\vba.txt", True, True)
    Fileout.Write "my string goes here"
    Fileout.Close`

**My Problem**

At line, Fileout.Write "my string goes here" I need to add characters that cause an error. I need to add " (Quotation mark) to the string as below.

```
Fileout.Write "#@~^jQUAAA==/KxdDP_|2I{;iI"2HK|jj3"P','CR!!ZTT!8@#@&Nr:~"
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try entering Chr(34)

replace(strString, """,chr(34))

"#@~^jQUAAA==/KxdDP_|2I{;iI"2HK|jj3" & chr(34) & "P','CR!!ZTT!8@#@&Nr:~"

Comment: Could you explain further how I would incorporate this into my code please, I am an amateur. Thanks.

Comment: I now understand, Thank you very much for your help. It is now working for me.